# R: error when trying to write an equivalent function n choose k

Tags: r, error-handling, binomial-coefficients

I'm taking the class of introduction for R programming.

we were asked to write a function that will be the same as n choose k:

```
choose(n, k)
```

we were asked to check if the function works by running n = 200, k = 50.

I wrote the following code:

```
    select_k <- function(n, k){
  sr <- c(log10(log10((factorial(n-1)/factorial(k-1)*factorial(n-k-2)))*(n/k)))
  return(sr)
}
```

as select_k is supposed to be the " n choose k".

my function works with values such as: 100 choose 25, but it doesn't work with greater values, like n = 200, k = = 50.

```
select_k( n = 200, k = 50)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In factorial(n) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
```

I have no idea what else can be done to fix that.

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you get an error or the wrong answer?

Comment: Instead of talking the `log(factorial())`, try using the `lfactorial()` function which is optimized for that particular operation. (though operates with base e)

Comment: yeah but when you put in:
choose( n = 200 , k =50), it works.

Comment: @MrFlick it doesn't matter that base e is much greater then the base of log10(log10))

Comment: @Jneven. The problem is that you are taking the log "too late". If you push the logs into the function so `log(factorial()/factorial())` becomes `lfactorial()-lfactorial()`, that's much easier for a computer to calculate.

Comment: @MrFlick  - actually, i got:  0.0096094

which seems much much too low.

Comment: Well, after taking the log, make sure to "re-inflate" at the very end with `exp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work for larger `n` because `factorial(n)` is too big:

```
> factorial(199)
[1] Inf
Warning message:
In factorial(199) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
```

This should return 200, but the computer only sees that you are trying to divide `Inf` by `Inf`:

```
> factorial(200)/factorial(199)
[1] NaN
Warning messages:
1: In factorial(200) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
2: In factorial(199) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
```

Obviously a lot of the multiplications in "n choose k" cancel out, so you'll need to avoid using regular factorial and only multiply the numbers that don't cancel out (`?prod` might be useful for you). Or (probably better) use the log version `lfactorial` to avoid running into numbers your computer can't store.

Edit: Added `lfactorial` recommendation from @MrFlick's comment

Comment: Though `exp(lfactorial(200)-lfactorial(199))` would work.

Comment: how would you recommend on defining this function for the general case?
i mean, this is obviously no problem of definfg it specificly for 200 choose 50, but i wouldn't know how to do it for n choose k greater then some N and some K, suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this {

```
a <- function(n, k) {
  exp(lgamma(n+1) - lgamma(n - k + 1) - lgamma(k + 1) )
}
```